# CREATE TABLE WITH NO DATA is very slow

Tags: postgresql

I'm running this SQL command on PostgreSQL 11:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS TABLE my_enormous_table WITH NO DATA;`

It takes 5 minutes to make the new table.

The `EXPLAIN ...` is:

```
Seq Scan on my_enormous_table  (cost=0.00..35999196.34 rows=143407234 width=3278)
```

Moving to a query like `CREATE TABLE ... (SELECT * FROM my_enormous_table WHERE FALSE);` is orders of magnitude faster - there is no seq scan, and the outcome is the same.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WITH NO DATA` still executes the query, it just ignores the result.

The better way to do that would be to avoid `CREATE TABLE ... AS`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_temp_table (LIKE my_enormous_table);
```

That also allows you to use the `INCLUDING` clause to copy default values, storage parameters, constraints and other things from the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_temp_table (LIKE my_enormous_table
                            INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
```

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly, I can't run `EXPLAIN` on this query, but the query works well, and quickly. Explain results in `ERROR: syntax error at or near "LIKE"`. More to learn!

Comment: You cannot run `EXPLAIN` on most DDL statements. Since these statements have no execution plan, that wouldn't make sense.